# Testing if three proportions follow hypothesized ordering

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, isotonic

I have a set of $n$ samples, and each sample $i$ is labeled with three binary characteristics $a_i,b_i,c_i\in \{0, 1\}$. I'm trying to test the hypothesis that the proportion with $a_i = 1$ is the largest, followed by the proportion with $b_i = 1$, followed by the proportion with $c_i = 1$. For instance, imagine I had the following binary outcome data for my 100 samples:

```
N <- 100  # I have 100 samples and will measure 3 different outcomes
datA <- rep(0:1, c(20, 80))  # outcome "A" occurs in 80% of samples
datB <- rep(0:1, c(40, 60))  # outcome "B" occurs in 60% of samples
datC <- rep(0:1, c(70, 30))  # outcome "C" occurs in 30% of samples
```

I'd like a test of the hypothesis that propA > propB > propC.

@kjetilbhalvorsen provided a very helpful suggestion in the comments to consider order-restricted inference, with a pointer to the `restriktor` R package that operates on linear models. I can "cludge together" a linear regression model 300 observations to estimate three different proportions from a set of 100 samples:

```
df <- data.frame(xA=rep(c(1, 0), c(N, 2*N)), xB=rep(c(0, 1, 0), c(N, N, N)),
                 xC=rep(c(0, 1), c(2*N, N)), y=c(datA, datB, datC))
mod <- lm(y~.-1, data=df)
summary(mod)

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ . - 1, data = df)
# 
# Residuals:
#    Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
#   -0.8   -0.3    0.2    0.4    0.7 
# 
# Coefficients:
#    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# xA  0.80000    0.04532   17.65  < 2e-16 ***
# xB  0.60000    0.04532   13.24  < 2e-16 ***
# xC  0.30000    0.04532    6.62 1.68e-10 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.4532 on 297 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.6412,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.6376 
# F-statistic: 176.9 on 3 and 297 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Then I can use the suggested package in a straightforward manner to test hypotheses on the ordering of coefficient values for my linear model:

```
library(restriktor)

myConstraints <- 'xA > xB
                  xB > xC'
iht(mod, constraints = myConstraints)
# Restriktor: restricted hypothesis tests: 
# 
# 
# Multiple R-squared remains 0.641 
# 
# Constraint matrix:
#    xA xB xC    op rhs active
# 1:  1 -1  0    >=   0     no
# 2:  0  1 -1    >=   0     no
# 
# 
# Overview of all available hypothesis tests:
# 
# Global test: H0: all parameters are restricted to be equal (==)
#          vs. HA: at least one inequality restriction is strictly true (>)
#        Test statistic: 61.6721,   p-value: <0.0001
# 
# Type A test: H0: all restrictions are equalities (==) 
#          vs. HA: at least one inequality restriction is strictly true (>)
#        Test statistic: 61.6721,   p-value: <0.0001
# 
# Type B test: H0: all restrictions hold in the population
#          vs. HA: at least one restriction is violated
#        Test statistic: 0.0000,   p-value: 1
# 
# Type C test: H0: at least one restriction is false or active (==) 
#          vs. HA: all restrictions are strictly true (>)
#        Test statistic: 3.1205,   p-value: 0.0009914
# 
# Note: Type C test is based on a t-distribution (one-sided), 
#       all other tests are based on a mixture of F-distributions.
```

I think the "Type C" test from `restriktor` is testing the hypothesis I care about (the ordering of the proportions). However, this linear regression approach seems "hacky" and unlikely to yield the correct p-values. Is there a specialized test for testing the ordering of proportions in "paired samples"?

Comment: You need order-restricted inference, see for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78860/hypothesis-test-between-ordered-categorical-independant-var-and-continuous-dep/598235#598235,

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks so much for the pointer. I updated my question based on your suggestion but feel I still haven't identified the test that is right for my data. Any suggestions for how to compare the ordering of proportions in paired samples?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `restriktor` in combination with a logistic regression model. A linear regression using `lm` is not appropriate for binary data.

First, fit an unrestricted logistic regression model using `glm` (I omit the intercept in my example below, but it's not necessary). Then use the `restriktor` function and `iht` function to carry out the hypothesis testing. The coefficients in a logistic regression model are log-odds. So the hypothesis can directly be applied to the coefficients because log-odds are just a monotone transformation of probabilities.

With your data, it could look something like this:

```r
library(restriktor)

# Simulate data

N <- 100  # I have 100 samples and will measure 3 different outcomes
datA <- rep(0:1, c(20, 80))  # outcome "A" occurs in 80% of samples
datB <- rep(0:1, c(40, 60))  # outcome "B" occurs in 60% of samples
datC <- rep(0:1, c(70, 30))  # outcome "C" occurs in 30% of samples

dat <- data.frame(
  y = c(datA, datB, datC)
  , g = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], rep(N, 3)))
)

# Fit logistic regression

mod <- glm(y~g - 1, data = dat, family = binomial)

# Use restriktor

restr_res <- restriktor(mod, constraints = c("gA > gB > gC"))

# Use iht

iht(restr_res, type = "C")

Restriktor: restricted hypothesis tests: 


Type C test: H0: at least one restriction is false or active (==) 
         vs. HA: all restrictions are strictly true (>)

 t-test statistic           p-value 
           3.0390            0.0013 

This test is based on a one-sided t-distributions on 297 residual 
degrees of freedom.


Constraint matrix:
   gA gB gC    op rhs active
1:  1 -1  0    >=   0     no
2:  0  1 -1    >=   0     no

unrestricted estimate:
      gA        gB        gC  
 1.38629   0.40547  -0.84730
```

The null hypothesis is rejected with $p = 0.0013$.